# Prefix match in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, prefix

Hey guys, I have a very simple problem in MATLAB:

I have some strings which are like this:

```
Pic001
Pic002
Pic003
004
```

Not every string starts with the prefix "Pic". So how can I cut off the part "pic" that only the numbers at the end shall remain to have an equal format for all my strings?

Greets, poeschlorn

Comment: Have you looked at any of the string-handling functions (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-42340.html#f16-6791)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'Pic' only ever occurs as a prefix in your strings and nowhere else within the strings then you could use [STRREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strrep.html) to remove it like this:

```
>> x = {'Pic001'; 'Pic002'; 'Pic003'; '004'}

x = 

    'Pic001'
    'Pic002'
    'Pic003'
    '004'

>> x = strrep(x, 'Pic', '')

x = 

    '001'
    '002'
    '003'
    '004'
```

If 'Pic' can occur elsewhere in your strings and you only want to remove it when it occurs as a prefix then use [STRNCMP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strncmpi.html) to compare the first three characters of your strings:

```
>> x = {'Pic001'; 'Pic002'; 'Pic003'; '004'}

x = 

    'Pic001'
    'Pic002'
    'Pic003'
    '004'

>> for ii = find(strncmp(x, 'Pic', 3))'
x{ii}(1:3) = [];
end
>> x

x = 

    '001'
    '002'
    '003'
    '004'
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your quick answer. In your example this works very fine :) Can you give me a hint how to transfer this on a cell array? Or otherwise tell me how to convert the cell array in a character array?

Comment: @poeschlom - You can convert a character array to a cell array by the [CELLSTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellstr.html) command.

Comment: I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, if I use cellstr(myCellArray) I get an error called "Input must be a string."...although all my string have the format as shown above and are stored in an <36x1 cell> (I have 36 input strings)

Comment: @poeschlom - I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. It sounds like your strings are already in a cell array. Do you want to convert them to a character array?

Comment: I think I have to do so!? Although I want to process this data in simulink and simulink can't access values in cell arrays...so this would be the way to do, or do I misunderstand this?

Comment: @poeschlom - I'm not familiar with Simulink so I can't really help you there. You can use either of the above two methods on both cell arrays and character arrays with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
strings = {'Pic001'; 'Pic002'; 'Pic003'; '004'};
numbers = regexp(strings, '(PIC)?(\d*)','match');
for cc = 1:length(numbers); 
    fprintf('%s\n', char(numbers{cc}));
end;
```